# Publishing Your Android Apps

Tags: android

Should one open up an LLC when publishing android apps?

Comment: Ask a lawyer, not a bunch of programmers.

Comment: This might be a better question for http://answers.onstartups.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont *HAVE* to, you can sell under your own name, you just have to pay the taxes on profits once you make more than $450 or so. Is it a good idea? If you plan on making more than what an LLC costs (through legalzoom its upwards of $400).

If you just plan on releasing hobby projects I would say wait on the LLC, until you finish some stuff that starts doing moderately well. You can still write off costs and everything under your own name. Main thing an LLC does is protect you from losing everything if you are sued. The most they can take is anything the "company" owns.